# I am trying to see the Block chain of twister

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am trying to parse the blk00000.bat file in my Ubuntu system . I am following the this document for help https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/block-parser-how-read-bitcoin-block-chain/  .
When i run the sight . py  code as : `python sight.py blk00000.dat'`
It show the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sight.py", line 25, in 
>       main()   File "sight.py", line 20, in main
>       parse(blockchain)   File "sight.py", line 11, in parse
>       block = Block(blockchain)   File "/home/amit-b3/Amit_Repo/blocktools-master/block.py", line 28, in
>   **init**
>       tx = Tx(blockchain)   File "/home/amit-b3/Amit_Repo/blocktools-master/block.py", line 58, in
>   **init**
>       output = txOutput(blockchain)   File "/home/amit-b3/Amit_Repo/blocktools-master/block.py", line 95, in
>   **init**
>       self.pubkey = blockchain.read(self.scriptLen) MemoryError

Please Help me.

Comment: You should post the code where you think the problem is occurring. Here the traceback gives you the exact line in which the program throws an error.

Comment: Hi, I take the code from here : https://github.com/tenthirtyone/blocktools/blob/master/block.py#L95